# Hover over chart shows multiple datapoints

Tags: chart.js

When I hover over a line chart with fairly dense datapoints (one entry per minute over several hours (24 hours eventually)) the tooltip shows me sometimes two or three sets (samples/rows) of datapoints. The additional datapoints appear to be adjacent samples.

[image: Multiple datapoint tooltip]

Looking at the generated Javascript source code definitely only has one set of points for each line at each time.

I am guessing the tooltip 'window' or 'aperture' is too big. Can I adjust this anywhere?

Working demo here:
    jsbin.com/nuqebazoci/1/edit?html,js,output

[This chart shows the temperatures on my solar hot water logging system]

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far? (attach the source code or a live example on jsbin for example)

Comment: Interesting exercise - I hadn't used jsbin before. I think this shows it https://jsbin.com/nuqebazoci/1/edit?html,js,output  I also tried pointHitRadius parameter but it didn't seem to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 'mode' param of the tooltip to 'index'

```
options :
   {
      ...
      tooltips:
         {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'index'
          }
      ...
   }
```

Comment: I'm glad that it solved your problem! :) Can you accept it as the answer then?

Comment: Of course - thought I had done that.  Done now. Thanks again.